# Java web scraper

Tags: java, html-parsing, htmlunit, html-content-extraction

What is the best library for a Java web scraper? I know the following choices:

1. Selenium
2. HTMLUnit
3. Lobo browser

I need to select one option to build a scraper for one scalable project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are scraping, why do you need a browser? Just doing basic cURL calls to a page and getting the response will give you what you need to do scraping.

This will help with scalability. If you want a browser then go for HTMLUnit as that would again help with scalability.

Answer (score 1):

I was recently recommended [Web Harvest](http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/index.php), and thought it worked well out of the box, except for some issues around HTTP 500 response codes ...

Answer (score 0):

Use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/), it works great to get the response from URL and then use the XPath Expression to parse data from the response. I've implemented this and it works great.